# Proof that if $z_0$ is a zero of order $k$ of $f$ then $\exists$ analytic $g$ saisfying this expression

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, singularity-theory

Let $f:S\to \mathbb{C}$ be analytic, $z_0 \in S$ be of order $k$ of $f$. Prove that there exists an analytic function $g$ satisfying
$$\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}=\frac{k}{z-z_0}+g(z)$$
$\forall z$ in $\varepsilon$-neighbourhood of $z_0$.

My **proof**:

Since $f$ is analytic at $z_0$, $\exists$ an analytic function $h(z)$ satisfying $f(z)=(z-z_0)^k h(z)$ on $N_\varepsilon(z_0)$. Then $f'(z)=k(z-z_0)^{k-1}h(z) + (z-z_0)^{k}h'(z)$ on $N'_\varepsilon(z_0)$. Hence, by division, $\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}=\frac{k}{z-z_0}+\frac{h'(z)}{h(z)}$ on $N_\varepsilon(z_0)$. Set $g(z):=\frac{h'(z)}{h(z)}$, where $g(z)$ is analytic since $\frac{h'(z)}{h(z)}$ is analytic.

Please let me know if you think this proof is good enough?

Comment: Sorry for my previous (deleted) comment; I misread the problem. But I think you should mention that $h(z_0)\ne 0$, since at this point you've shown that $g$ is analytic on $N_{\epsilon}(z_0)\backslash\{z_0\}$, but you haven't shown it can be extended to an analytic function on $N_{\epsilon}(z_0)$.

Comment: You should also mention that $h(z_0)\ne0$ implies that there's a whole neighborhood of $z_0$ on which $h(z)\ne0$ (since you're dividing by $h(z)$).

Comment: " $z_0$ be of order $k$ of $f$ " means ?

Comment: By the theorem which implies that $f(z) = (z-z_0)h(z)$, h(z) is analytic and non-zero at $z_0$. This in turn implies that $h(z)$ is non-zero in a small neighbourhood of $z_0$.